# Bootstrap modal "covering" other elements when hidden (2.3.2)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that I have tailored with some CSS.  Now when it is hidden, it is covering other elements (which is not allowing me to click links and such).  What could be happening?  What I have seen is that in the modal div it has the style "display:block" even when it is hidden, which could be explaining the issue.  Also removing position: absolute from the CSS solves the problem, but then when the modal comes up, it is not positioned correctly.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal1 hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <article class="modalTopPart welcome-modal-top">
    <p>Hello!</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="center">
    Hello again!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left:50%;
  z-index: 111111;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: -390px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: What does your `hide` css look like?  If it's hidden, it should not be visible at all.  Is the issue only happening after dismissing the modal or even on page load?

Comment: It sounds like it's being hidden with `visibility: hidden` and overlapping your content. You could try hiding it with `display: none` or by giving it something like `left: 2000px` when it's not active.

Comment: When I look at it in dev tools, the .hide class is being overruled, but by what I don't know.  Also, I've tried adding display:none to the div itself and it still gets overrun with display:block.

Comment: nm, adding display:none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `z-index:` to your CSS code. This can control your '3D view' of your page.

Imagine if you were to take each individual element of your page and put it on top of one another 3 dimensionally. If you have `z-index:-10;`, for example then that element will be placed 10 spaces back from where it normally stands.

```
.modal1 {
  z-index:-10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left:50%;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: -390px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made that trick

```
#bootstrapModalFadeWindow
{
    margin-top:5000px;
}
```

Then it doesn't overlaps anything. Actually it is under the border of page. Then in js just remove this option property on click. It turns back after form hides.

```
.on("click","#buttotThatShowsModalWindow",function()
{
    $("#activateForm").css("margin-top","0px")
})
```